# mxmlc with both linked and not linked rsls?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, rsl

On the mxmlc command line, I can include paths to RSL files.  I can choose to link these RSLs at runtime by setting

```
-static-link-runtime-shared-libraries=false
```

What if I need to link to *some* rsls and embed (static-link) other rsls?  Is there a way to set the link settings for each rsl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in a flex config file:

```
<compiler.include-libraries dir="C:\rsls\" append="true">
    <library name="yrCoolLibrary.swc" />
</compiler.include-libraries>
```

command line (via ant):

```
<arg line="-compiler.include-libraries C:\rsls\yrCoolLibrary.swc"/>
```

Comment: http://forums.adobe.com/message/2097152;jsessionid=44F69E72B1E297EAC9BD0352A0D91C40.node0